# How to make a percent stacked barchart where each bar shows the relation between 2 different things?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a plot about football statitics and have 2 data frames, as an example 1 has Home Goals scored and the other has Away goals scored and so forth. Is it possible to make a stacked barchart where each bar is the ratio of 2 things from different data frames? I can only find help for a barchart where each bar shows the ratio of the same things on the x axis.

Here's some sample dataframes.

```
home

      HTGS       HTGC        HTP       HTGD 
35.7923977 19.0087719  1.7241305  0.8221233 

away

      ATGS       ATGC        ATP       ATGD 
35.9736842 18.9444444  1.7564932  0.8349917
```

Tried using r graph gallery examples with ggplot in various ways but can't even get close to what i would like, was only able to get a chart where x axis had the home and away and y had the relatsionship between the columns.

Edit:I have no real code to show, got something with AI and tried stuff I found on stackoverflow, but nothing even remotely close to what I would like

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But if you want a concrete answer with code, please provide a reproducible example including a couple of (dummy) data frames to better illustrate your problem, as well as the code you have already tried. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AllanCameron added some sample data frames. I have no real code to add, I know it's bad practice, but just cant figure anything out

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of visualization you have in mind so I opted for showing the home-away-ratio of each variable. The main task however is to first create one dataframe for which I use `dplyr::bind_cols` and to reshape the data for plotting for which I use `tidyr::pivot_longer`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- bind_cols(home, away) |>
  pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = c(".value", "variable"),
    names_pattern = "(.)(.*)"
  ) |>
  rename(home = H, away = A) |>
  mutate(ratio = home / away)

ggplot(dat, aes(variable, ratio, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(width = .6) +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
home <- structure(list(
  HTGS = 35.7923977, HTGC = 19.0087719, HTP = 1.7241305,
  HTGD = 0.8221233
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -1L
))

away <- structure(list(
  ATGS = 35.9736842, ATGC = 18.9444444, ATP = 1.7564932,
  ATGD = 0.8349917
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -1L
))
```